# JavaScript syntax issue: [{ }] hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, nested

I came across the following nested array and am little confused as to why it uses this particular syntax:

```
var allQuestions = [{
   question: "Which company first implemented the JavaScript language?",
   choices: ["Microsoft Corp.", "  Sun Microsystems Corp.", "Netscape Communications Corp."],
   correctAnswer: 2
}];
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/alxers/v9t4t/

Is it common practice to use
                    `[{...}]`
having declared a such a variable?

Comment: It's an array containing a single object. It's perfectly fine, assuming more objects will be added later on. How else would you create an array containing an object?

Comment: It is perfectly fine, it represents an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is an array with an object literal in it. It is not realy a nested array. The

```
{
 question: "Which company first implemented the JavaScript language?",
 choices: ["Microsoft Corp.", "  Sun Microsystems Corp.", "Netscape Communications Corp."],
 correctAnswer: 2
}
```

is an object literal, which your array contains. In the fiddle you linked to there are several of these defined in the `allQuestions` array. By doing this it makes it easy to loop over the array of questions and display each in turn.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I understood the concept of using the array to display the individual questions. I guess I got a little confused with the combination of the object literal.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening there is listing the object inside an array, example:

```
[{id:1, value:"any"}, {id:2, value:"any any"}]
```

So here we have declared array with two objects in it. Another so called "traditional" approach would be:

```
var arr = [];
var obj1 = {id:1, value:"any"};
arr.push(obj1);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `allQuestions` variable is supposed to be "an array of questions", where each question is an object with properties like `question`, `choices` or `correctAnswer`.

If it was declared just as `var allQuestions = {question: ..., choice: ...}`, it would be just the one object. Further code which want to know the number of questions `allQuestions.length` or access e.g. the first question's test as `allQuestions[0].question` would not work.

Try adding more questions and you will see what the extra brackets are for:

```
var allQuestions = [
  { question: "1st...", ...},
  { question: "2nd...", ...},
  ...
];
```

Comment: I realise this is quite simple now. As you mentioned it was supposed to be an "array of questions" which it actually is in the fiddle example. My simplified code doesn't make that clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`allQuestions` is just an array of objects and yes, it is common practise.

Comment: Thx, but I don't get it: The question is "Is it common practice to use  [{...}] having declared a such a variable?" so I'm anwering "..yes, it is common practise."